# How to restrich script tag in url?

Tags: pci-compliance, cross-site

PCI scan fail because 
website url all to pass script tag in url.

https://www.muddsauce.com/index.php/<SCRIPT>alert('SAINT')</SCRIPT>

Scan Report:
Summary: 
web program allows cross-site scripting in PATH_INFO (/thank_you.php)

Information From Target:
Service: https
Sent:
GET /thank_you.php/alert('SAINT') HTTP/1.0
Host: www.muddsauce.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Connection: Keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ub27m3bj36f42q7d9kvkv348c0

Received:
http://del.icio.us/post?url=http://www.muddsauce.com/thank_you.php/alert('SAINT')&title=Thank You - muddsauce.com Gourmet BBQ Sauce' target="about:_blank">